# How to add option to play video fullscreen in youtube webiew

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I have a Youtube Webview and its working well.
Now I want to add an option to play the video in fullscreen as in the Youtube official app.

How can I add the option to play the video in fullscreen?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
WebView wb;
TextView tv;
private boolean exit = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activty_main);
    wb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
   tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    checkConnection();
  }

  protected boolean isonline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) 
  getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
     NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is my Webview setting when I start the app on my phone, it does not show the fullscreen play option .

```
private void checkConnection() {
    if (isonline()) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You are connented to Internet", 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        wb.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/?gl=IN");
        WebSettings webSettings = wb.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "You r not connected to Internet", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        tv.setText("Can't Connected to the Server. \n Please Check your 
Internet Connection");
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (wb.canGoBack()) {
        wb.goBack();
    } else {
        if (exit) {
            finish();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Press again to exit", 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                exit = false;
            }
        }, 2000);

        exit = true;
    }
    }
```

This is my layout file

```
 <RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/web"
    tools:ignore="RtlCompat">

</WebView>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Use the youtube api instead of loading youtube in a webView

Comment: It will be better if you use YouTube Android Player API instead Webview. You can handle  Full Screen and other control. Check this documentation https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/

Comment: You can use youtube SDK

Comment: I want simple code someone can do this ???

Comment: @Shohel Rana sir can i use free youtube api or paid ??   please tell me youtube api free or paid ????

Comment: @JagsirSingh Youtube api totally free. Use this tutorial for integration.

https://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/how-to-play-youtube-video-in-android-app/

Or follow below url

https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/

Comment: @ Shohel Rana thank you sir

Comment: @JagsirSingh You are most welcome

Answer (score 0):

Is your code working ?
its playing only audio 
no video is showing